# How do I Force the Background color on web pages IE9 Win7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, accessibility

Normally opening up internet options , and adjusting the "accessability" type features for colors, and fonts, would allow a person to control how a web page was viewed.  (rant) that is what the item has been there for for 15 years.

The functions of "Color" Background fail to work properly here. Also the use of my Own Css.style sheet thing leaves the background stark white , instead of black.
Only shifting to a "high contrast" scheme for the desktop (not the browser) changes that.
and then it cannot be turned the other way :-)
The acessability item for "ignore colors on web pages" is enabled (as required).

In short, the desktop colors are controlling my browser web page colors in IE9
Changing the "render type" to software does not change it.
Using the Help in the color and accessability locations , brings up "Topic Not Found" Not available for this version of windows.
IE9 was added to my system via Windows Update

I checked in XP running IE8 and it works as one would expect.
I tested both the 32bit and 64bit versions.
I believe , but am not sure now, that I had done this in IE8 in windows7.

Is this a specific flaw of IE9 or W7?   I mean another Microsoft feature?
Or am I doing something wrong again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is done.

I have made the necessary steps to test this here. I removed IE9, tested IE8, re-fresh installed the OS, and tested IE8 again, then re-Updated to IE9.  Consistently IE9 fails to make this accessibility change correctly.